# Android Linkify how to set custom link color?

Tags: android, linkify, textcolor

I want to set my android linkify text color to a custom color however `mText.setLinkTextColor("#2f6699");` does not work, I have been searching for a built in method that will compile a hexidecimal value but I havent found one, any help will go a long way thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should convert it to a Color. 
Try:

```
mText.setLinkTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2f6699"));
```

Comment: What about WebView? `Spannable sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(html)); Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL); webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(path, Html.toHtml(sp), "text/html", "utf-8", null);` How to change link color in this situation?

Answer (score 23):

You can use also `android:textColorLink="#2f6699"` in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

`noteView.setLinkTextColor(Color.green);`

If you want to set an hexadecimal color:

`noteView.setLinkTextColor(Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue));`

Replacing alpha/red/green/blue with the desired values.
The documentation on the Color class can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Answer (score 2):

As resources.getColor() function deprecated we can try this alternative way.

textView.setLinkTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorBlue))

Thanks.